# SQLite3 stores nonreadable text

Tags: c, database, encoding, sqlite

I used SQLite3 to implement small application to read from or write to a database. Some records that  need to be added to the database are Arabic texts and when they are stored to the database they converted to non-readable and non-understood texts. I use these APIs for write & read:

- sqlite3_open
- sqlite3_prepare
- sqlite3_bind_text
- sqlite3_step

What can I do to solve the problem ?

Comment: What encoding is your text in in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that your text is in non-ASCII encoding. For example, in unicode.

This is because ASCII table has only characters represented by integer numbers from 0 to 127. So there is nothing that can be used to represent Arabic letters. For example, Unicode is using five different ranges to represent Arabic language:

- Arabic (0600—06FF, 224 characters)
- Arabic Supplement (0750—077F, 48 characters)
- Arabic Presentation Forms-A (FB50—FDFF, 608 characters)
- Arabic Presentation Forms-B (FE70—FEFF, 140 characters)
- Rumi Numeral Symbols (10E60—10E7F, 31 characters)

And since there could be more letters/characters that a 8-bit value (`char` type, which has a length of 1 byte) would allow, wide character is used to represent some (or even all) of those letters.

As a result, the length of the string in characters will be different from length of the string in bytes. My assumption is that when you use `sqlite3_bind_text` function, you pass a number of characters as a fourth parameter, whereas it should be a number of bytes. Or you could misinterpret this length when reading the string back from the database. The `sqlite3_bind_text` documentation is saying this about the fourth parameter:

> In those routines that have a fourth argument, its value is the number
>   of bytes in the parameter. To be clear: the value is the number of
>   bytes in the value, not the number of characters. If the fourth
>   parameter is negative, the length of the string is the number of bytes
>   up to the first zero terminator.

Make sure you do the right thing there.

See also:

- [Wide characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character)
- [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)
- [Arabic characters in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_characters_in_Unicode)

Good luck!

Comment: Unicode is not an encoding.  Unicode is typically encoded as UTF-8 or UTF-16 (the latter is mostly used on Windows).